# No qualifying bean found for dependency Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dao, autowired

I'm developing a program using spring, and i'm facing this problem, it says:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [com.owlexa.cms.dao.MemberProductDao]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

in my observation, the problem is in my service / service impl here's the details

Service:

```
public interface MemberService {

Member findMemberByPK(Integer id);
void deleteMember(Member obj);
void saveOrUpdateMember(Member obj);
Page<Member> findMemberListing(MemberSearchParams params, Pageable pageable);
Member findMemberByColsAndValues(String[] cols, Object[] values);

/*MemberProduct*/
Page<MemberProduct> findMemberProductListing(MemberProductSearchParams params, Pageable pageable);
MemberProduct findMemberProductByColsAndValues(String[] cols, Object[] values);
}
```

and my ServiceImpl

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class MemberServiceImpl implements MemberService{

    @Autowired
    MemberDao memberDao;

    @Autowired
    MemberProductDao memberProductDao;

    MemberSearchParams memberParams = null;

    MemberProductSearchParams memberProductParams = null;

    @Override
    public Member findMemberByPK(Integer id) {
        return memberDao.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void deleteMember(Member obj) {
        memberDao.delete(obj);
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void saveOrUpdateMember(Member obj) {
        memberDao.save(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Member> findMemberListing(MemberSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        return memberDao.findListing(params, pageable);
    }

    public Member findMemberByColsAndValues(String[] cols, Object[] values) {
        memberParams = new MemberSearchParams();
        memberParams.setEqColumns(cols);
        memberParams.setEqValues(values);

        Page<Member> member = memberDao.findListing(memberParams, null);

        if(member != null && !member.getContent().isEmpty()){
            return member.getContent().get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<MemberProduct> findMemberProductListing(MemberProductSearchParams params, Pageable pageable) {
        return memberProductDao.findListing(params, pageable);
    }

    @Override
    public MemberProduct findMemberProductByColsAndValues(String[] cols, Object[] values) {

        memberParams = new MemberSearchParams();
        memberParams.setEqColumns(cols);
        memberParams.setEqValues(values);

        Page<MemberProduct> memberProduct = memberProductDao.findListing(memberProductParams, null);

        if(memberProduct != null && !memberProduct.getContent().isEmpty()){
            return memberProduct.getContent().get(0);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

help me to fix the problem, with your solutions please,
thx in advance.

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Also add the code of `MemberProductDao` and his implementation

Comment: You probably do not have MemberProductDao yet or you forget to properly annotate it with for example @Repository.

Comment: And while you're at it, please share the Spring configuration (Java or XML)

Answer (score 0):

I believe atleast one of the Autowired fields in the MemberProductDAO is not spawned by the Spring. Please share your MemberProductDAO file and also your Spring.xml file to debug more.